# Applescript for Contacts: how to process only addresses from local contacts and skip addresses from Facebook?

Tags: applescript, abaddressbook

On the Mac, when using integration with Facebook, Contacts (Address Book) shows Facebook contacts as well as local/iCloud contacts. In the Groups view (Cmd-1) it is possible to view All Contacts, or only iCloud, or only Facebook contacts.

I have created an Applescript script that processes addressed, but it should only process the non-Facebook addresses/contact.
How can I determine that a address/contact is a **regular** address/contact, not a **Facebook** address/contact?

I checked all the groups, it does not show group names like "iCloud" or "Facebook", so I can not filter on that.

E.g. I could have "John Doe" stored locally with his work address, and in Contacts it is combined with the Facebook details, so also his home address is shown. When editing I see the Facebook "F" next to his home address. In my script I only want to process (for John) his work address.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not very satisfactory, but it seems to work: Facebook entries appear to only ever be members of a single group, with name "addressbook".

Comment: I will check. You are right: not ideal, but if that's indeed the case I will mark the item as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's it. It seems to behave like a different kind of group though. If I list all groups (repeat with mygroup in groups \ log name of mygroup as string \ end repeat) it does not show "addressbook" or "card" (=regular card), but it does show these when I ask for the groups that a partical person belongs to.